# Edit function code to append results into empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, append

I have a function below, where I'd like to append the results of each like into an empty list so that I can call that list outside of the function.

How can I adjust it? Currently there's no error but it simply prints "[]" when print(cd) when I print outside of the function. I'd like to be able to put the new data in a list, then recall it outside of the function.

```
 cd = [] # started empty list
def split_lines(lines, delimiter, remove = '[0-9]+$'):
  for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split(delimiter)
    tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
    cleaned_list = list(filter(lambda e:e.strip(), tokens))
    cd.append(cleaned_list) # tried appending here
    print(cleaned_list)
```

Comment: It would be useful if you include the error message.

Comment: You need to `return` a value, then assign/add it to `cd`.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what went wrong, because you didn't include an error message, output, or an example of how you call this function and what it results in.  Calling `cd.append` should "work", resulting in a list of lists, although it would be better to build a new list and return it as MattDMo suggests.

Comment: You probably want `cd.extend(cleaned_list)`. `append()` will nest the new list into `cd`.

Comment: your code works fine for me.  what is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll have to include more explanation next time. My issue is when I print(cd) outside of this function it returns "[]". Where I want it to print my list of lists, or the data that I can recall outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues I noticed

1 - `print(cleaned_list)`
Do you want to print the `cleaned_list` or `cd`

2 - If `.append()` doesn't work for some reason, maybe do

```py
cd = [] # started empty list
def split_lines(lines, delimiter, remove = '[0-9]+$'):
  for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split(delimiter)
    tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
    cleaned_list = list(filter(lambda e:e.strip(), tokens))
    cd = cd + cleaned_list
    print(cleaned_list)
```

I don't get why `append` wouldn't work but just in case.

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to write the data the function is producing into a new list (cd) then be able to recall that list outside of the function.

Comment: Then do add this to the end of the function

#stuff before the function
def split_lines(######)
#the code goes here
return cd

output = split_lines()


Or you can use global variables

Answer (score 0):

### This might be your problem:

You have to call split_lines and then print cd.

```
cd = [] # started empty list
def split_lines(lines, delimiter, remove = '[0-9]+$'):
  for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split(delimiter)
    tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
    cleaned_list = list(filter(lambda e:e.strip(), tokens))
    cd.append(cleaned_list)
split_lines("call me first", " ")
print(cd)
```

###### btw - cd is not a good name to use its a terminal command.